# laravel 419 expired error for get method or gateway link (a tag) when callback

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, csrf

By default, error 419 is displayed in Laravel when enter or callback from bank gateway by using the post or get method or link (a tag). The problem is solved when I make changes to the session file as follows:

```
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE = true;
same_site = none;
```

but some users still have a 419 error when callback from the bank gateway.

- All caches has been cleared.
- force redirect to https has been set;
- set all callback urls in VerifyCsrfToken.php

and

> - SESSION_DOMAIN = null
> - SESSION_LIFETIME = 525000

This only happens to some users.

please help me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling sessions as cookies, then some browser caches may be holding on to cookies without the new headers.

This would explain why it occurs for some users and not others (especially if your cookies have long expiry).

If possible, get one of your end users to clear their cookie for you site using the browser development tools. For Chrome it should be something like:

`F12` -> `Application` -> `Cookies` -> "Clear All"

Comment: thank you. one of the sites handling sessions as cookie. can i clear or expire user browser cookies?
but another site handling sessions as file and some users have the same problem!

Comment: I don't know of a good way of expiring cookies remotely i'm sorry to say. No matter what method of session control you are using, at some level the browser will need to keep track of it. I think even your file sessions will use a cookie on the client side!